# How to test photo interrupters

Tags: diodes, integrated-circuit, photodiode, testing, photoresistor

I have come upon two photo interrupters in a calibration kit circuit. The circuit seems to not respond. How can I check these photo interrupters? The green LED is responding when an object is brought in between.

[image]

Comment: Re, "The circuit seems to not respond... The green LED is responding..." It's a bit unclear what the problem actually is that you want help with. Maybe you could explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

> The circuit seems to not respond.

How would you expect it to respond?

> How can I check these photo interrupters?

Insert an opaque object in the slot.

> The green LED is responding when an object is brought in between.

It's working!

Comment: I use it on a CNC machine to do the needle calibration. But when I check the output on the machine, it shows ‘1’ on one of the sensor, where it is suppose to show “00” for both.

Comment: For anyone to help diagnose the problem we would need the datasheet for the module and the CNC inputs.